# Converting a .VOB file into .mp4 or other format to decrease the video size

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a folder that contains few .VOB format file. The folder actually contains a movie and typically a movie of that length would occupy 2 to 5 GB but the folder I have is 18 GB!

Is there any way I can convert it to .mp4 or any other format to reduce the space it occupies?

I have tried the following command, (not sure what it does exactly) but I ended up with the same size of video.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.VOB -c:v copy -c:a copy out2.mp4 2> log.txt
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're stream copying (re-muxing) the video and audio with `-c:v copy -c:a copy`. Think of it like a copy and paste.

If you want to reduce the size you'll need to re-encode it. The simplest command would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.vob output.mp4
```

- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more details.
- For max compatibility I suggest also adding `-vf format=yuv420p` as an output option (put it before `output.mp4`).

Comment: The folder size reduced from 18GB to 4GB, thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 thanks for adding this answer, llogan!  My GF has an old Winderz laptop that struggles with the VOBs, and she's trying to sift through a million old home movies.  You're a lifesaver!